# iPad1, use the 30pins VGA cable

Tags: ios, ios5, vga

I'm working on a simple application for a vacation with friends. It's something like the Wheel of Fortune.

The problem is that we with too much people to look at the iPad1, so I was thinking to beam the application. I got the 30pins VGA connector that I use for keynote and Adobe Idea, so I think it's possible.

I don't find something on the internet, or I can't figure it out how to search this specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bit off source code that helps

http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output/

:-)

Answer (score 0):

There's also this: https://github.com/freespace/TVOutManager which I was able to get working.
(this is an improved fork of work by Rob Terrell).

I didn't realise that the lack of video mirroring by default is a problem was **only with the iPad 1** (which I don't have to support) as detailed here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4108